# cakephp 3.x how to set routing for admin related actions

Tags: routes, cakephp-3.0

i have create a admin login function in my UsersController and its working fine and i have create rule for admin routing  in my routes.php file my routes.php code for admin routin is below

```
Router::prefix('admin', function ($routes) {
    // All routes here will be prefixed with `/admin`
    // And have the prefix => admin route element added.

    $routes->connect('/', ['controller' => 'Users', 'action' => 'login']);

});
```

and my users controller function is below

```
function login() {
    $this->set("title_for_layout", "Login to your account");
    $user = $this->Users->newEntity();

    if ($this->request->is('post',"put")) {

        if(!empty($this->request->data)){
            $user = $this->Auth->identify();
            if ($user) {
                $this->Auth->setUser($user);
                return $this->redirect(['controller'=>'users','action'=>'dashboard']);
            }
        }
    }
    $this->set(compact("user"));
    $this->viewBuilder()->layout('login');
}
```

as shown ablove code after login i redirect the admin user to dashboard but when i login it always show the error that A route matching could not be found as shown in image [image]

please tell me what should i do to slove this problem also as cake 2.0 we only add one rule for admin and front and after that use redirect or href link to redirect to other controller and action so is there any way that i have created the above rule for routes not its automatically redirect to users contoller dashboard function or i have to create routes for every action

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your idea about prefix routing is not correct. See http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/routing.html#prefix-routing

Answer (score 0):

```
Router::prefix('admin', function ($routes){
    $routes->connect('/', ['controller'=>'Users', 'action'=>'login']);
    $routes->connect('/:controller/', [], ['routeClass' => 'Cake\Routing\Route\InflectedRoute']);
    $routes->connect('/:controller/:action/*', [], ['routeClass' => 'Cake\Routing\Route\InflectedRoute']);
});
```

Your problem should be fixed! :)